# Why is this jQuery function not recognized?

Tags: jquery

With some help from the fine folks on Stackoverflow, I built a small newsletter subscription submission form:

```
 <div id="news-signup">
      <form action="news.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <input type="text" id="your-email" name="your-email" value="YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS" onfocus="if (this.value=='YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS') this.value='';" />
          <input type="submit"  value="::Submit Query::" id="red-submit" />
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Here is the jquery that replaces the form with a confirmation message:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#news-signup form')
    .validate({
     submitHandler: function(form) {
       $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            success: function() {
            var Image = $('<img />').attr({src:'_images/register-thanks.png', width:332, height:35, alt:"Success"});
                $('#news-signup form').hide();
                $('#news-signup').append(Image);
            }
       });
     }
  });
});
```

This works perfectly on this [page](http://movingsimplified.com/), but the replacement image does not kick in on this [page](http://movingsimplified.com/helpful_videos.html).

I would appreciate some direction to resolve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see why this should not work (but I also prefer PrototypeJS) but what happens, if you get rid of all this form stuff and register a click callback on the submit button? Something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="news-signup">
    <input type="text" id="your-email" name="your-email" value="YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS" />
    <input type="submit"  value="::Submit Query::" id="red-submit" />
</div>
```

I also got rid of the inline scripts (don't do this).

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var emailInput = $("#your-email");

    emailInput.focus(function() {
        //  THREE = !
        if(this.value === "YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS") {
            this.value = "";
        }
    });

    emailInput.blur(function() {
        if(this.value === "") {
            this.value = "YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS";
        }
    });

    $("#red-submit").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'news.php',
            data: {
                'your-email': emailInput.val()
            },
            success: function() {
                var image = $('<img />').attr({src:'_images/register-thanks.png', width:332, height:35, alt:"Success"});
                $('#news-signup input').hide();
                $('#news-signup').append(image);                
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Let me know, if it worked. And by the way always use 3 = when comparing objects.

Comment: Hi Phil. This is very close. I put the code in and the form is replaced by the image, however, it also goes to news.php. There must be one more step to prevent the page from loading. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok. Did you remove the <form> Tag from the HTML? This one is no longer needed. Plus you could also try to change the <input type="submit" ... /> into <input type="button" ... />. As the javascript does all the form handling for you, you don't have to specify this button as the submit button.

Comment: Hey :) did it work now? If yes, would be cool, if you accept my answer, if not, give me an update so that we can figure it out together.